# Array sorting. Where do the arguments come from?

Tags: javascript

Where do the arguments a and b come from in this sorting function?
Are they passed automatically?

```
dir = "asc"
sortArray = new Array("hello", "Link to Google", "zFile", "aFile");

//sort array
if (dir == "asc") {
    sortArray.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.toLowerCase() > b.toLowerCase()
    });
} else {
    sortArray.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.toLowerCase() > a.toLowerCase()
    });
}

    for (var i = 0; i < sortArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(sortArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: `a` and `b` take on the values of each pair of elements in the array.

Comment: Just so you know, your code is wrong. A sorter is supposed to return `-1` or `1` depending on if `a` is less than `b`, respectively, or `0` if they are equal. What your code is doing is either returning `0` or `1`. So if the script compares `X` and `Y`, then it will be told that `Y>X` and `X==Y`, which is illogical and so the result is undefined. Add `?1:-1;` to the end of each `return` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are they passed automatically?

Yes.

You are creating an anonymous comparator function, which the `sort` function calls whenever it needs to compare two objects.

Answer (score 0):

These are passed *automatically* to your sort function. Placing names for them in the parameters list of your anonymous function is merely a convenience. You could see all items passed to your function by logging the `arguments` collection:

```
sortArray.sort(function() {
    console.log( arguments );
});
```

Which results in the following log:

```
["hello", "Link to Google"] // 0 vs 1
["Link to Google", "zFile"] // 1 vs 2
["zFile", "aFile"]          // 2 vs 3
```

These two variables would be `arguments[0]` and `arguments[1]`, representing two items from your array that ought to be compared. The return value of this comparison should be `-1`, `0`, or `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting algo including two parts - pick-rearrange logic and element comparison logic. 
Javascript runtime library will handle pick-rearrange logic (e.g. quick sort), and when it picking two elements and need a comparison result, it will call the function in the array.sort parameter to get it.